# fontawesome doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter-bootstrap-rails (3.2.1 from git) with rails 4.2. I have added @fa-font-path: "/assets" to make fontawesome work in development. However, it still doesn't work under production.

The error message is like:

```
assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0 404 (Not Found)
```

The precompiled file is:

```
public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-9bf0604ed1778de864df7e69a3348217.ttf
```

When I check the generated application.css, it's like

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0");src:url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0") format("embedded-opentype"),url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0") format("woff"),url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0") format("truetype"),url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg")
```

I am guessing the mismatch of the file name caused the problem. But don't know how to update the application.css to use the file generated by precompile.

However, the glyphicon works fine.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by using font-awesome-rails gem, and comment out the awesome config in the bootstrap_and_override.css file.